# the meaning of "as can"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

http://htmldog.com/guides/html/advanced/html5forms1/

step, min, and max attributes can be used with dates and times, too, **as can** the CSS pseudo classes to style according to validity.

The structure of the above context is strange for me. I mean why after "as" there is a question format?
I wonder "as" in the above context means "in the same way" or "because"

Comment: It is poorly written. "As can" means "as also can" in this context. However, we are not a proof-reading service and cannot rewrite bad English for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form *X can VP, as can Y* may be expanded to *X can VP, and Y can VP as well*, where *VP* is a *verb phrase*.

The usage is idiomatic, and has the same form as the following dictionary entry:

> **as against**
>   Compared or contrasted with.
>   *‘the adult literacy rate for women is 44.5 percent, as against 67.8 percent for men’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as)

Other similar forms include:

- as is - *The guitar wire is digging into her flesh; as is the gravel of the roof terrace.* - [Collins Dictionary, quoting Sean Thomas THE CHEEK PERFORATION DANCE](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-is);
- as would - *Does a stock dividend dilute the price per share as would a forward stock split?* - [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/stockdividendvsstocksplit.asp); and
- as does - *As Communication Improves, Culture Improves, As Does The Bottom Line* - [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amyanderson/2015/06/28/as-communication-improves-culture-improves-as-does-the-bottom-line-4-tools-that-make-a-difference/#75a903061cb7)

Your quote can be rewritten as:

- Step, min, and max attributes can be used with dates and times, too, to style according to validity. The CSS pseudo classes can be used with dates and times, too, to style according to validity.

Comment: would you please rewrite my context in the plain English. in this way I can learn much more.

Comment: @ARAM *Done*. :)

Comment: I guess in the answer, Z should be changed to Y. I wonder if I am right.

Comment: @ARAM Yes, thanks for catching that. I've corrected the mistake.